# Typical ref counting for a handler pipeline

Tags: netty

Trying to upgrade to Netty 4.1.17.Final, I'm facing a ref counting issue for the following pipeline.

- The first handler is framing the raw input from `ByteBuf`: waiting there are at least the minimal amount of `readableBytes` to consume a frame, putting all the frames that can be read from this raw input in the `output` (in/out `List` parameter). The frames are derived buffers, using `readSlice`.
- The second handler is parsing each frame as an application specific class (not ref counted).

As far as I understand, only the second handler should call `release()`.

Unfortunately, it raises `IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0` for some cases (when the buffer is recycled) in the first, when trying to `readIntLE`.

It's unclear to me whether in such handler pipeline/chain, the first one should `retain` the buffer, or not use derived buffer, ...

---

Edit #1: Contrary to what I understand from the documentation, `readRetainedSlice` doesn't really "behaves similarly to readSlice(...).retain()" in such case, as the buffer returned by `readRetainedSlice` has a `refCnt` different from the parent one.

---

Edit #2: Filtering the leak detection details with `leakDetection.acquireAndReleaseOnly=false`, it seems the issue is on the outbound side.

```
23:20:55.586 ERROR [s.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector] :: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
#1:
    io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:88)
    io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:113)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:256)
    io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.doWrite(EmbeddedChannel.java:724)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901)
    io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedUnsafe$1.flush(EmbeddedChannel.java:820)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1321)
        ...
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:300)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:92)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:89)
    NettyEmbedder$.withChannel(NettyEmbedder.scala:95)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:89)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:50)
        ...
#2:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.retain(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:36)
    io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.retain(ReferenceCountUtil.java:40)
    io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.doWrite(EmbeddedChannel.java:722)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901)
    io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedUnsafe$1.flush(EmbeddedChannel.java:820)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1321)
        ...
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1041)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:300)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:92)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:89)
    NettyEmbedder$.withChannel(NettyEmbedder.scala:95)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:89)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:50)
#3:
    Hint: 'DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext#0' will handle the message from this point.
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:810)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.write(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:104)
    NettyEmbedder$$anon$1.write(NettyEmbedder.scala:88)
        ...
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:304)
    reactivemongo.core.protocol.MongoHandler.write(MongoHandler.scala:91)
        ...
Created at:
    Hint: 'NettyEmbedder$$anon$1#0' will handle the message from this point.
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:810)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:113)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:304)
    reactivemongo.core.protocol.MongoHandler.write(MongoHandler.scala:91)
        ...
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:300)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:92)
    ChannelFactorySpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ChannelFactorySpec.scala:89)
    NettyEmbedder$.withChannel(NettyEmbedder.scala:95)
        ...
```

Comment: If you need to use a Netty ByteBuf inside your application POJO, you need to implement a release methods for your POJOs.

Comment: As said, there is no ref counted/able data after the second handler, reason why the question is about the pipeline

Comment: Please show your first handler... what type does it extend / implement ?

Comment: It's a ByteToMessage, which decode to the next handler w/ readSlice(..).retain : https://github.com/cchantep/ReactiveMongo/blob/49bde9b63a95b2d20f9ae44ae41104a5bf3f154c/driver/src/main/scala/core/protocol/protocol.scala#L189

Comment: @NormanMaurer I'm wondering whether some case/misusage of [`EmbeddedChannel` with concurrency](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4827) could lead to such issue? Currently the leak detector is complaining about a test using such channel, if and only if the pipeline is configured with outbound handler, and if and only if this test is executed along with another one not using any `EmbeddedChannel`

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at your code and there is a buffer leak:

https://github.com/cchantep/ReactiveMongo/blob/49bde9b63a95b2d20f9ae44ae41104a5bf3f154c/driver/src/main/scala/core/protocol/protocol.scala#L241

This calls `frame.readBytes(readableBytes)` which will return a new allocated `ByteBuf` that you just drop on the floor without calling `release()`. While calling `release()` here should fix this leak I would suggest just calling `frame.skipBytes(readableBytes)` which will also discard it but without the allocation and memory copy.

Hopefully this should fix it.

Please note my Scala skills are a bit rusty so maybe I missed something :)

Comment: Thanks for your time @norman-maurer . In the [latest test](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7482#issuecomment-350222087), the trace is reproduced by the test using `EmbeddedChannel` w/o the inbound handler calling `readBytes`, so I think that's not related.